# Von Neumann Bicomutant theorem detail

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

at some point in the proof of the thoerem of double commutant of Von Neumann, you have to show that

$$\pi(\mathcal{M})'' = \pi(\mathcal{M}'') $$

I was looking the proof on *Theory of Operator Algebras I*, by Takesaki and I don't understand why he constructs all this coming stuff to get the above result.

Basically he denotes $\mathcal{H}$ a fixed Hilbert space and $\{\mathcal{H}\}_{i \in I}$ a family of replicas of $\mathcal{H}$. Then we call
$$ \tilde{\mathcal{H}} = \sum_{i \in I}^{\bigoplus}\mathcal{H}_i$$

Let now be $U_i$ the isometry of $\mathcal{H}$ onto $\mathcal{H}_i$. For any perator $x \in \mathcal{L(\tilde{H})}$, putting

$$x_{i,j} = U_i^*xU_j \hspace{4mm} i,j \in I,$$

we obtain a matrix $(x_{i,j})$ of bounded operators on $\mathcal{H}$. Clearly the map
$$x \in \mathcal{L(\tilde{H})} \rightarrow (x_{i,j})$$

is injective, so we may write $x = (x_{i,j})$.

For each $x \in \mathcal{L(H)}$ we define an operator $\tilde{x} \in \mathcal{L(\tilde{H})}$ by $\tilde{x} \sum_{i \in I}^{\bigoplus}\xi_i = \sum_{i \in I}^{\bigoplus}x\xi_i$.

Then the map

$$\pi:x \in \mathcal{L(H)} \rightarrow \tilde{x} \in \mathcal{L(\tilde{H}})$$
is an isomorphism of $\mathcal{L(H)}$ into $\mathcal{L(\tilde{H})}$

What we have to show now, knowing this preliminaries, is that

*For an operator* $\tilde{x} \in \mathcal{L(\tilde{H})}$ to be of the form $\tilde{x} = \pi(x)$ *for some* $x \in \mathcal{L(H)}$ *it is necessary and sufficient that* $\tilde{x}$ commutes with all $U_iU_j^*$

And especially on the implication ($\Leftarrow$), I'd need some help to formalize it.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Let $$\pi: \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H}) \to \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H}^{\oplus n}): T \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} T & & \\ & \ddots &\\ &&T \end{pmatrix}.$$

Then we have for any unital C*-subalgebra $A \subset \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ that $\pi(A)' = M_n(A')$. (why?).

Where $M_n(C)$ denotes the C*-subalgebra of $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H}^{\oplus n})$ consisting of those linear maps such that if we restrict them to the i-th copy of $\mathcal{H}$ and compose them with the projection onto the $j$-th copy of $\mathcal{H}$, we get an element of $C$ (and this for any $1 \leq i,j \leq n$).

Next prove that for any unital C*-subalgebra $B \subset \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ we have that $M_n(B)' = \pi(B')$.

Combining these two it is easy to conclude that $\pi(A)'' = M_n(A')' = \pi(A'')$.